# Yield variable scope with Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, yield

How does Ruby distinguish the codeblocks `|n|`'s in the functions yield case of "Kim" and the function call's case of "Eric"?

Apologies if this is painfully obvious - I really don't see how exactly the `|n|` variable in the codeblock with the function(arg) call effects the functions internal yield call?

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield..."
  yield("Kim")
  puts "... now in between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end
```

```
>>> yield_name("Eric") { |n| puts "My name is #{n}." }
```

> ```
> In the method! Let's yield...
> My name is Kim.
> ... now in between the yields!
> My name is Eric.
> Block complete! Back in the method.
> ```

As I understand the code block, it reads, "for each argument, put to screen "My name is #{that argument}". How does Ruby pass "Kim" into "that argument" so it prints "My name is Kim" instead of just "Kim"? Thank you.

---------------------- EDIT

Here's a less confusingly named example:

```
def double(parameter)
    yield parameter
    yield 7
end
```

When I invoke:

```
>>> double(3) { |n| puts "how? #{n * 2}" }
```

I get:

> ```
> how? 6  #<-- relative to function call(arg)
> how? 14 #<-- relative to internal functions yield call(arg)
> ```

So how does Ruby know to use yield 7 in the puts statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand the code block, it reads, "for each argument, put to screen "My name is #{that argument}"

Nope. Literally, it reads "pass argument 'Eric' to method `yield_name` and also pass this block". The mere fact that you passed a block to method means nothing. The method can simply just **not call** it (also known as "yielding to block"). So you can't make any assumptions about number of block invocations or values of supplied parameters without knowing implementation of the method.

In this case, we do know the implementation

```
def yield_name(name)
  puts "In the method! Let's yield..."
  yield("Kim")
  puts "... now in between the yields!"
  yield(name)
  puts "Block complete! Back in the method."
end
```

Here we see that per each call, `yield_name` calls its block two times. First, with a static value (`"Kim"`). Second time, it simply relays its parameter `name`. If there were no `yield` statements here, the block you supplied would be completely ignored (and, therefore, nothing would be printed). But we do trigger the block two times and see two lines in the output.

Comment: This is great. I have a lot to learn! The distinction of static value and parametric value helps. That functions call their code blocks is something I don't have a lot of experience with but now I can think about it more accurately! If I understand correctly the yielding to the code block passes the static variable "Kim" into the scope of the code blocks local `|n|` parameter?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy: yes, exactly. When you do `yield "Kim"`, the block is called and its parameter `n` is `"Kim"`.

Comment: YaY! much obliged :D

Answer (score 1):

You could view the block as being conceptually similar to the method:

```
def my_block(n)
  puts "My name is #{n}."
end
```

And the `yield`s as calling it:

```
my_block("Kim")
my_block(name)
```

In other words, the `n` is the argument of the block, and it gets its value from the `yield`, which triggers the block's execution every time a value is yielded.

Comment: so when `yield("Kim")` gets called while `yield_name("Eric")`s block is executing, `yield(arg)`s value gets passed through to the variable value of the block? ...i think I am seeing it come together, thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy I didn't follow the reasoning there. When you call `yield_name("Eric") { |n| … }`, you are passing `"Eric"` (as `name`) and the block to `yield_name`. Neither `name` or the block is used or executed automatically. When you `yield "Kim"`, the block is executed and `"Kim"` is passed to it (`name` has not been used at this point at all, and might never be used, it makes no difference). `yield name` is a completely distinct case that happens later.

Comment: poo. I still don't get it. Thank you for your patience as I struggle. Maybe using "yield_name(name)" was [a bad choice](https://youtu.be/2FM3Em7FIOc?t=7s)...

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy: "when yield("Kim") gets called while yield_name("Eric")s block is executing" - it's the other way around. Block executes __when__ you do `yield("Kim")`. If you don't yield, block doesn't run.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - the correction of my error in describing the events is very helpful! If you would provide an answer exposing my error(s) and articulating the proper order of execution (or how to think about it) I'd gladly accept the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy: I think Arkku provided pretty accurate description in his last comment. Do you find it not as clear?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree Arkku has provided a very apt explanation of the proper order of execution, but I am still having trouble exposing the errors of my own thinking as stated in the OP. If no one else offers an answer, I will of course select Arkku's. Best & thanks again.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks - Arkku's answer helps, but it is an analogy and I would like to know what and how Ruby is actually handling recursive yield parameters :)

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy: there's no recursion here. And no recursive yield parameters.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev HA! That makes a big difference in how I see it now!!! Thank you for exposing the error of my ways - helps so much just to accurately describe the issue :D